# Validating and submitting forms returned by multiple components using a single 'submit' button

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to create a beginner cv builder app with react.
App.js class component returns these child components `<PersonalInfo />`, `<Experience />`, and `<Education />` and a 'submit' button (`type: 'button`, `text: 'submit'`), inside a div. Additional `<PersonalInfo />` and `<Experience />` components can also be returned upon clicking an 'add' button placed below each of them.

Depending on the `isSubmitted` state of each of those components, they may either return a `form` or a `div` containing user inputed values.

I wanted the button on App.js to be able to validate and submit the forms returned by the child components to prevent user from submitting with empty fields.

I've tried adding the below function in App.js which is called when the 'submit' button is clicked:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

    if(forms.length) {
      forms.forEach(form => form.requestSubmit();
    }
 }
```

but the input fields don't get validated and the forms are not submitted.

Here's how `<Experience />` is rendered:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import uniqid from "uniqid";
import Experience from "./CVForm/Experience";

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     // other states for other components here *\
      experienceValues: [
        {
          id: uniqid(),
          jobTitle: "",
          employer: "",
          from: "",
          to: "",
          mainResponsibilities: "",
          submission: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

// event handlers here

  render() {
    const { personalInfoValues, educationValues, experienceValues } =
      this.state;

return (
  <div>
       <h2>Work Experience</h2>
    {experienceValues.map((el) => {
      return (
        <Experience
          key={el.id}
          id={el.id}
          experienceValues={experienceValues}
          onExperienceChange={this.onExperienceChange}
          onExperienceEdit={this.onExperienceEdit}
          onDeleteExperience={this.onDeleteExperience}
          onExperienceSubmit={this.onExperienceSubmit}

        />
      );
    })}
    <button type="button" onClick={this.onAddExperience}>
      Add
    </button>
    <button type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Main;
```

Experience.js

```
import React from "react";
import uniqid from "uniqid";

function Experience(props) {
  const {
    id,
    experienceValues,
    onExperienceChange,
    onExperienceEdit,
    onDeleteExperience,
    onExperienceSubmit
  } = props;
  const experience = experienceValues.filter((el) => el.id === id)[0];
  const experienceArr = Object.entries(experience);

  return (
    <section>
      {experience.submission ? (
        <div>
          {experienceArr.slice(1).map((el) => (
            <p key={uniqid()}>{el[1]}</p>
          ))}
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              onExperienceEdit(id);
            }}
          >
            Edit
          </button>
          {experienceValues.length > 1 && (
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => {
                onDeleteExperience(id);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={onExperienceSubmit}>
          <input
            name="jobTitle"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Job title"
            value={experience.jobTitle}
            onChange={(e) => onExperienceChange(e, id)}
            required
          />
          <input
            name="employer"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Employer"
            value={experience.employer}
            onChange={(e) => onExperienceChange(e, id)}
            required
          />
         // other input fields here
        </form>
      )}
    </section>
  );
}

export default Experience;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a validate function based on 4 fields, Name, Phone Number in Personal Details, University in Educational Details and Organizational Details.

Function can be modified based on requirements but if it is required to just have a value, then below works fine.

Features :

1. On clicking submit, navigates to page which has missing values.
2. On successful submit, shows the values
3. All values validated in single function in case there are any dependencies.

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import FormComponent from './Components/form'
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <FormComponent />
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Form Component

```js
import React from 'react'
import EducationInfo from './EducationInfo'
import PersonalInfo from './PersonalInfo'
import ProfessionalInfo from './ProfessionalInfo'
class FormComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name : "",
        university : "",
        PhoneNumber : "",
        CurrentOrganization : "",
        pageSwitch : 1,
        submitSwitch : false
    }
    updateName = (e) => {
        this.setState(
            {name : e.target.value}
        );
    }
    updateUniversity = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            university : e.target.value
        });
    }
    updatePhoneNumber = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            PhoneNumber : e.target.value
        });
    }
    updateOrganization = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            CurrentOrganization : e.target.value
        });
    }
    nextPageSwitch = () => {
        this.setState({
            pageSwitch : (this.state.pageSwitch + 1)
        });
    }
    previousPageSwitch = () => {
        this.setState({
            pageSwitch : (this.state.pageSwitch - 1)
        });
    }

    validateSubmit = () => {
        if(this.state.name.length > 0) {
            if(this.state.PhoneNumber.length > 0) {
                if(this.state.university.length > 0) {
                    if(this.state.CurrentOrganization.length > 0) {
                        this.setState({
                            submitSwitch : true
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        this.setState({
                            pageSwitch : 3
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    this.setState(
                        {
                            pageSwitch : 2
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
            else {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        pageSwitch : 1
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        

        
        return(
            <div>
                <p>This is a Form</p>
                <label>Input Name : </label><input type="text" onChange={this.updateName}/>
                {this.state.pageSwitch === 1 ? <PersonalInfo PhoneNumber={this.state.PhoneNumber} updatePhoneNumber = {this.updatePhoneNumber}/> : 
                    this.state.pageSwitch === 2 ? <EducationInfo university = {this.state.university} updateUniversity = {this.updateUniversity}/> : 
                    <ProfessionalInfo CurrentOrganization = {this.state.CurrentOrganization} updateOrganization = {this.updateOrganization} />
                }
                <button type="button" disabled= {this.state.pageSwitch === 3 ? true : false } onClick={this.nextPageSwitch} >Next</button>
                <button type="button" disabled = {this.state.pageSwitch === 1 ? true : false} onClick={this.previousPageSwitch} >Previous</button>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.validateSubmit} >Submit Form</button>
                {this.state.submitSwitch === true ? <p>Successful Submit
                    Name : {this.state.name}
                    Phone : {this.state.PhoneNumber}
                    University : {this.state.university}
                    Organization : {this.state.CurrentOrganization}
                </p> : <p>Entries Missing</p>}  
                    
            </div>
        );

    }
}

export default FormComponent;
```

Personal Info.js

```js
import React from 'react'

class PersonalInfo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Personal Information</p>
                <label>
                    Enter Phone Number : 
                </label>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.props.updatePhoneNumber} value={this.props.PhoneNumber}/>
            </div>
        );

    }
}

export default PersonalInfo;
```

Educational Info.js

```js
import React from 'react'

class EducationalInfo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Educational Info</p>
                <label>
                    Enter University : 
                </label>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.props.updateUniversity} value = {this.props.university}/>
            </div>
        );

    }
}

export default EducationalInfo;
```

Professional Info.js

```js
import React from 'react'

class ProfessionalInfo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Professional Info</p>
                <label>
                    Enter Current Organization : 
                </label>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.props.updateOrganization} value={this.props.CurrentOrganization} />
            </div>
        );

    }
}

export default ProfessionalInfo;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Instead of displaying a paragraph stating that entries are missing when a user has not filled all inputs, is it possible to add a required attribute to the inputs and let the user know which filled is empty upon clicking the 'submit' button just like in an HTML form? (Kindly see the pieces of code I've added in the edit)